# Trouble Using ImageMagick - Installed Thru Homebrew

Tags: perl, imagemagick, homebrew, perlmagick

I installed ImageMagick thru Homebrew successfully - so it seems, anyways - but when I tested it thru Perl using

```
perl -le 'use Image::Magick'
```

I received this error:

```
Cant load '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle'
for module Image::Magick: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle, 
1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 204.
 at -e line 1
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
&Image::Magick::constant not defined. The required ImageMagick libraries are not installed or not installed properly.
END failed--call queue aborted at -e line 1.
```

I did some research, and apparently Perl is not supported by default when ImageMagick is installed through Homebrew, so I tried installing PerlMagick, the ImageMagick API for Perl. I used the following commands after downloading the source:

- cd Documents/PerlMagick-6.88
- perl Makefile.PL
- make
- sudo make install

So I thought that I successfully installed PerlMagick, yet it didn't change my situation in the slightest. I'm new to ImageMagick and Homebrew (just converted from Macports), so I may be doing something completely wrong here.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve my situation? Specifically, what would be the cause of

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
```

error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install `PerlMagick` manually since using Homebrew to install ImageMagick.

Try this:

```
$ brew uninstall ImageMagick
$ brew install ImageMagick --with-perl
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This got it working! I now have another problem on my hands, but I'll address it in a separate question if I can't figure it out. Thanks!